# How to remove red X from network shortcuts

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, desktop

### Background

Before COVID19, my PC was connected to the company network.
I created some shortcuts to network folders (such as my home drive), on my PC Desktop.

Upon COVID19, I am working at home via VPN (Cisco Anyconnect), with the same PC.
After successful connection with the VPN, my network shortcuts have a red 'X' on them:
[image]

### Question

How do I get Windows to *refresh* or redraw the icons without the red 'X' after I have successful VPN connection?

**Environment**
Windows 7 PC
Citrix AnyConnect (for VPN)
I don't have full admin privileges on the PC.

Comment: Connect by VPN, click on the shortcut and it should renew. It may take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Sorry, double clicking or single clicking does not remove the red 'X'.  I've waited hours to no avail.

Comment: You need to ask your Company Support what might be happening in your case. I have seen this at clients and just clicking on the folder works. Also remember that Windows 7 is well out of support and that may be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with Windows 7, If you try to access or browse the mapped drive, can it reconnects?

If that is your case, to resolve this behavior, you can change the default time-out period on the shared network computer. To do this, use one of the following methods.

Method 1: Using Registry Editor

Method 2: Using Command line
For more details, please refer to the microsoft official doc:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drive-connection-to-network-share-lost

Method 3:Or you can run a batch file that remaps the drive upon logging in.

net use [drive]: /delete

net use [drive]: \server\share /user:[user] [password] /persistent:yes

Comment: After the connection to VPN is successful, I can double click on the icons to access the folders.  The issue is not connectivity, but the red 'X' on the icon.  After I double click on the icon, the red 'X' does not go away.

Comment: I'm doing a remote connection to my employer's network.  What should the default timeout period be?  hours? days?  I also logoff when I am not using the PC.